# Can i move two subclass of QObject to the same QThread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I have two subclasses of `QObject`:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void process();
};
```

And

```
class ThreadController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ThreadController(QObject *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void sleep();
    void wakeUp();
private:
    QMutex *mutex;
    QWaitCondition *wc;
};

void ThreadController::sleep(){

    mutex->lock();
    wc->wait(mutex);
    mutex->unlock();
}

void ThreadController::wakeUp(){
    mutex->lock();
    wc->wakeOne();
    mutex->unlock();
}
******************************************************
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    Worker* worker = new Worker;
    ThreadController*controller=new ThreadController();
    controller->moveToThread(thread);
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    QObject::connect(thread,&QThread::started,worker,&Worker::process);
    QObject::connect(&w,&MainWindow::wakeClicked,controller,&ThreadController::wakeUp);
    QObject::connect(&w,&MainWindow::sleepClicked,controller,&ThreadController::sleep);

    thread->start();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

I move the worker and controller to the same `QThread`. I want to control the thread (put to sleep or wake up) by the `ThreadController` and the worker just doing its work, now the idea can not work, the worker can doing process but the controller can not work, I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: ThreadController::ThreadController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    mutex=new QMutex();
    wc=new QWaitCondition();
}

Comment: What does `Worker::process` look like? Do you have some infinite loop there? If so, then your `ThreadController::sleep` is never executed. Also, you have to wake the thread up from some other thread, so `ThreadController::wakeUp` will not work with your signal/slot method (unless you make it a direct connection).

Comment: @thuga would you mind giving me some advices more about that why infinite loop can not be stopped by the QWaitCondition out of the loop. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Because your `ThreadController::sleep()` method is a slot (as it should be), and infinite loops block the event loop, your `sleep` slot is never executed. If you use slots in a thread, then you shouldn't use infinite loops. If you want to simulate an infinite loop, use a `QTimer`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @thuga yes,just as you say. Worker::process is a infinite loop like that:

```
void Worker::process(){

    int a=(int)QThread::currentThreadId();
    emit sendThreadId(a);
    int b=0;
    while (b<1000000) {
       b++;
       emit processResult(b);
       QThread::msleep(1);// signal emit too quickly will block the main thread，                 
                          //so i just let the loop slow down 
   }
}
```

**Why ThreadController::sleep is never executed if the process is infinite loop,but the ThreadController::wakeup can be executed i had tested.**
 [image]

```
QObject::connect(&w,&MainWindow::wakeClicked,controller,&ThreadController::wakeUp,Qt::DirectConnection);
```

yes the directconnection let it work.thanks!And i havs some questions:when a QThread uses QWaitCondition::wait() will stop the event loop in it? So any signal sends to the thread will not be processed anymore？

i want to reuse the QThread in my program.When the worker finishs its work will send a signal to the controller,and the controller will execute the sleep()function.Next time the data comes,controller wakeup() the thread and the worker goes to work again. Has any other solution to suit this case ？Reuse QThread or Delete it and new it(which Performance loss more)？

Comment: now i got it. When the worker is doing infinite loop,which is blocking the thread's event loop.So the signal to execute the sleep() will not be processed ,but the wakeup() function will be execute beacuse of the Qt::DirectConnection i had only use in the connection of the wakeup slot. Qt::DirectConnection just lets the wakeup() runs in the main thread beacuse the wakeup signal is emitted from main thread.

Comment: Correct. You just have to replace your infinite loop with a `QTimer`.

Comment: @thuga thx again. I have another question: Is it worth to reuse a QThread with a QWaitCondition ? Or just to new a QThread when it is needed.        To create a Thread will consume a lot of resources ?

Comment: What do you mean? Reuse in what way?

Comment: @thuga  Reuse in this way: when the worker finish its work,it will send a sleep signal to the controller and the controller will let the workerthread go to sleep.When new data comes,controller wakes up the workerthread and the worker goes to work again. Is it worth to do that or just create a new QThread when it is needed.

Comment: You don't have to put the thread to sleep when there is nothing to do. But if you want to kill the thread once the work is done, you should use `QRunnable` or `QtConcurrent::run`. Read about the different threading technologies in Qt [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html).

Answer (score 0):

@thuga I need the signal&slot in the workerthread.But QtConcurrent::run could not provide such a mechanism.You should be correct that we don't have to put the thread to sleep when there is nothing to do. And i just finished the job with your help. Although my solution is not good，i posted all the code as shown below：

Worker Class for doing heavy jobs.

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void processResult(int);
    void sendThreadId(int);

public slots:
    void process();
};

void Worker::process(){
  QEventLoop eventloop;
  int a=(int)QThread::currentThreadId();
  emit sendThreadId(a);
  int b=0;
   while (b<1000000) {
      b++;
      emit processResult(b);
      QThread::msleep(1);
      eventloop.processEvents();
  }
    qDebug()<<"Worker::process() called";
    qDebug()<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    eventloop.exec();
}
```

---

ThreadController class for controling the worker QThread to sleep or wakeup.

```
class ThreadController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ThreadController(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~ThreadController();
signals:
      void statusChanged(QString);
public slots:
    void sleep();
    void wakeUp();
private:
    QMutex *mutex;
    QWaitCondition *wc;
};

ThreadController::ThreadController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    mutex=new QMutex();
    wc=new QWaitCondition();
}

ThreadController::~ThreadController(){
   delete mutex;
   delete wc;
}

void ThreadController::sleep(){
    qDebug()<<"ThreadController::sleep() called";
    qDebug()<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    emit statusChanged("WorkerThread sleeping");
    mutex->lock();
    wc->wait(mutex);
    mutex->unlock();
}

void ThreadController::wakeUp(){
    qDebug()<<"ThreadController::wakeUp() called";
    qDebug()<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    emit statusChanged("WorkerThread wakening");
    mutex->lock();
    wc->wakeAll();
    mutex->unlock();
}
```

---

MainWindow Class for making a simple GUI(two QPushButtons and several QLabels)

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
signals:
    void wakeClicked();
    void sleepClicked();
public slots:
    void setMainId(int);
    void setThreadId(int);
    void setThreadStatus(QString);
    void setThreadCount(int);
private:
     QLabel*l_mainThreadId;
     QLabel*l_workerThreadId;
     QLabel*l_workerThreadStatus;
     QLabel*l_workerThreadCount;
     QString count;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    setWindowTitle("Threading Test");
    QWidget *window=new QWidget;

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout=new QVBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout1=new QHBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout2=new QHBoxLayout;

    QLabel*label1=new QLabel("Main Thread ID:");
    l_mainThreadId=new QLabel;

    int a=(int)QThread::currentThreadId();
    QString idlabel=QString::number(a);
    l_mainThreadId->setText(idlabel);

    mainLayout1->addWidget(label1);
    mainLayout1->addWidget(l_mainThreadId);

    QPushButton* wakeButton=new QPushButton("WakeUp");
    QPushButton*sleepButton=new QPushButton("Sleep");

    mainLayout2->addWidget(wakeButton);
    mainLayout2->addWidget(sleepButton);

    mainLayout->addLayout(mainLayout1);
    mainLayout->addLayout(mainLayout2);


    QVBoxLayout *threadLayout=new QVBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *threadLayout1=new QHBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *threadLayout2=new QHBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *threadLayout3=new QHBoxLayout;

    QLabel *label2=new QLabel("Worker Thread ID:");
    l_workerThreadId=new QLabel;

    threadLayout1->addWidget(label2);
    threadLayout1->addWidget(l_workerThreadId);

    QLabel *label3=new QLabel("Worker Thread Status:");
    l_workerThreadStatus=new QLabel;

    threadLayout2->addWidget(label3);
    threadLayout2->addWidget(l_workerThreadStatus);

    QLabel *label4=new QLabel("Counting Result:");
    l_workerThreadCount=new QLabel;

    threadLayout3->addWidget(label4);
    threadLayout3->addWidget(l_workerThreadCount);

    threadLayout->addLayout(threadLayout1);
    threadLayout->addLayout(threadLayout2);
    threadLayout->addLayout(threadLayout3);

    QHBoxLayout *layout=new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addLayout(mainLayout);
    layout->addLayout(threadLayout);

    window->setLayout(layout);

    setCentralWidget(window);
    setThreadStatus("WorkerThread wakening");

    QObject::connect(wakeButton,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::wakeClicked);
    QObject::connect(sleepButton,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::sleepClicked);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::setMainId(int id){

   QString idlabel=QString::number(id);
   l_mainThreadId->setText(idlabel);

}

void MainWindow::setThreadId(int id){

     QString idlabel=QString::number(id);
     l_workerThreadId->setText(idlabel);
}

void MainWindow::setThreadStatus(QString s){

    l_workerThreadStatus->setText(s);
}

void MainWindow::setThreadCount(int i){
    count = QString::number (i) ;
    l_workerThreadCount->setText(count);
}
```

---

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    Worker* worker = new Worker;
    ThreadController*controller=new ThreadController();
    controller->moveToThread(thread);
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    QObject::connect(thread,&QThread::started,worker,&Worker::process);    QObject::connect(worker,&Worker::processResult,&w,&MainWindow::setThreadCount);
    QObject::connect(worker,&Worker::sendThreadId,&w,&MainWindow::setThreadId);
    QObject::connect(&w,&MainWindow::wakeClicked,controller,&ThreadController::wakeUp,Qt::DirectConnection);
    QObject::connect(&w,&MainWindow::sleepClicked,controller,&ThreadController::sleep);
    QObject::connect(controller,&ThreadController::statusChanged,&w,&MainWindow::setThreadStatus);

    thread->start();
    return a.exec();
}
```

---

The Program:
[image]